# data not inserting in my table in php mysql with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, insert, where-clause

```
<form method="post"  action="insert.php" >

<p>Name:<input type="text" name="food_name"  id="food_name"/>

<p>Price:<input type="text" name="food_price"  id="food_price"/>

<?php 

$query = "SELECT * FROM category";  

// Execute it, or return the error message if there's a problem.  

 $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); 

//$options = "";

$dropdown = "<select name='cat_name'>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 

{

 $dropdown .= "\r\n<option value='{$row['cat_id']}'>{$row['cat_name']}</option>";

}

$dropdown .= "\r\n</select>";

echo $dropdown;

?>

 <input type="submit" value="Insert Price" />

<a href="show.php">Cancel

</form>
```

//this is the form which taking data from dropdown menu and textboxes

X======================X

```
if(isset($_POST['cat_name'])!= '')

{

$cat_id=$_POST['cat_name'];

$food_name=$_POST['food_name'];

$foodPrice=$_POST['food_price'];


$query="INSERT INTO food (food_name,food_price) values( $food_name,$foodPrice) where 

cat_id= $cat_id";

if(mysql_query($query))

{

echo "new item added";

}

else

{

die(mysql_error());} 

}

?>
```

this is the error 
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where cat_id= 4' at line 1"

it should insert the food name and price by selecting the category

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a where clause on an insert, it would make no sense, if you need to set the id then pass it in as one of the parameters, if it is an auto increment then just don't include it.

```
$query="INSERT INTO food (food_name,food_price,cat_id) values(\"$food_name\",$foodPrice,$cat_id)";
```

Look into using mysqli or PDO though when it comes to sql queries, don't use the mysql_* versions.  You should look into using prepared statements that will help safeguard you against sql injection.

Comment: $query="INSERT INTO food (food_name,food_price) values( $food_name,$foodPrice) AND cat_id= $cat_id";

CAN I USE IT LIKE THIS?

Comment: um no, if `cat_id` is a column in the food table and it is not an auto increment column then you do it like this `$query="INSERT INTO food (food_name,food_price,cat_id) values( $food_name,$foodPrice,$cat_id)`.  Why are you putting **cat_id** seperatley? Is there somme reason we are not understanding?  Or are you trying to update an existing item?

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing `insert` and `update` statements. In `insert` there is not `where` clause. You are just adding a record to the table without any conditions

```
INSERT INTO food (food_name,food_price) values('$food_name', $foodPrice)
```

It you want to update a record you can do this:

```
update food set food_name = '$food_name', food_price = $foodPrice
where cat_id= $cat_id";
```

Comment: it is inserting and updating the database where as I want to insert the food item with respect to category.

Comment: Please explain in more detail.

Comment: I just want to insert data into my table for it I am using insert statement but there is condition in insertion i.e insert the data with respect to category.Just like I am inserting zinger burger in the table which comes inder the category of fastfood.then when I click on the fastfood it sholud show the zinger burger.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the query as follows

```
$query="INSERT INTO food (food_name,food_price) values('".$food_name."','".$foodPrice."');
```

If cat_id already available means you have to update the table by using update query

```
update table food set food_name='$food_name' , food_price ='$foodPrice' where cat_id = $cat_id;
```

Comment: it is inserting and updating the database where as I want to insert the food item with respect to category.

Comment: I just want to insert data into my table for it I am using insert statement but there is condition in insertion i.e insert the data with respect to category.Just like I am inserting zinger burger in the table which comes inder the category of fastfood.then when I click on the fastfood it sholud show the zinger burger.

Comment: Can u please give your DB Schema?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use WHERE in INSERT-statements.

You have 2 options:

Make an update:

```
UPDATE food SET food_name=<food_name>, food_price=<food_price> WHERE cat_id=<cat_id>;
```

or make an INSERT (where food_name+cat_id has an unique-index in this example) this way:

```
INSERT INTO foot (cat_id, food_name, food_price) VALUES (<cat_id>, <food_name>, <food_price>) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE food_price=VALUE(food_price);
```

This `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` is an mass-update statement.

Comment: I just want to insert data into my table for it I am using insert statement but there is condition in insertion i.e insert the data with respect to category.Just like I am inserting zinger burger in the table which comes inder the category of fastfood.then when I click on the fastfood it sholud show the zinger burger.

Comment: my second task is to insert and retrieve image from the database.for insertion I have to select the omage from the harddrive.

Comment: This is a new question. You should start a new one. But I am sure, this topic has been solved here a number of times... You should mark one of these answers here as "accepted answer", too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already set the id, then edit it.

`UPDATE food SET food_name = "Name", food_price = "Price" WHERE cat_id = $cat_id`
You don't need a where clause on an insert

Comment: I just want to insert data into my table for it I am using insert statement but there is condition in insertion i.e insert the data with respect to category.Just like I am inserting zinger burger in the table which comes inder the category of fastfood.then when I click on the fastfood it sholud the zinger burger.